# Custom parameters dynamic remarketing

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to implement dynamic remarketing for adwords for my ecommerce site. I understand the customer parameters pull from my merchant feed.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
ecomm_pagetype: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
ecomm_totalvalue: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
};
</script>
```

I think I understand how to put in a value from my merchant feed for prodid and totalvalue but I don't know what to do with pagetype.  Any help would be appreciated.

Best,

John

Answer (score 1):

ecomm_pagetype is not supposed to map to your product feed. It's a signal you send to Adwords that will allow you to segment your audience and create list. Recommended values are home, category, product, cart, purchase.
Then in Adwords, you will be able to create lists for product viewers, cart abandoners, past purchasers etc...
You need to pass a fixed value for each page or group of pages on your site.